# Where does it still make sense to use Flash?

Tags: javascript, flash, html

It seems that Javascript, CSS3, and HTML5 are handling more and more of what Flash used to do. Plus, mobile devices have been slow to support Flash. Where does it still make sense to use Flash in web design & development?

For instance, in the projects I work on, we're still using Flash for video playback in Internet Explorer but using HTML5 in other browsers. I'm guessing audio is similar. Flash still has some advantages for complex animation and games. Where else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an absolute fan of javascript and a real Flash lover - but this argument is really starting to grate me.

Please by no means assume I'm slating you - and it is a valid question, but they both excel in their extremes.

There is a *now* a cross over between the two platforms. With the new onslaught of groovy HTML5 trickery and Javascript speed going through the roof - you can now perform tasks in JS of which you would used to only do in Flash.

Stem the argument slightly to what Flash can do:

- Augmented reality with 3D scenes using camera and sound.
- file and data manipulation of which will far exceed javascript current role.
- cross platform support on multiple browsers and devices
- extended Rich media
- Standardized video support
- For clients, Flash replacements for custom fonts is a must as copyright licensing on their fonts prohibits CSS3 fonts. No mentioning the need to have 4/5 versions of the same fonts in different formats.
- deploy applications quickly via desktop and web using the same platform/language/code

No to mention the recent advancements:

- GPU acceleration to the like of installed apps capability
- native massive networking support

With javascript - difference in implementation across browsers can be a halting process.

If I were to display video on my website in flash, its one SWF. To ensure I have the same visibility with the relatively new HTML5/Javascript/CSS3 application - I would need to distribute my video in **many** formats with multiple levels of CSS capabilities with JS fallbacks.

---

By no means am I stating Flash is the first and foremost - but its still the go to technology for many tasks I need to do day-to-day.

Additionally we really only questioned the way the web was going since apple didn't implement Flash on their platform. Its a decision I happily live with and don't miss - but with the allowance to build an app using Flash and then to Deploy it as a native iOS app - this argument is now subjective to fan bases and those without the wish to support a new workflow.

---

This is a site I help build in flash/AS3:

http://www.adobemuseum.com/index.php

Building the exact thing in javascript to work in IE6 would have made me quit my job.

If you don't agree, I'd love to hear your opinion and I'm totally willing to argue my point further or listen to a reason as to why I am wrong.

Comment: regarding fonts: typekit and webfonts.fonts.com solve that problem.

Comment: @Thomas - Cheers dude - fontsquirrel.com is my favourite so far. But it doesn't escape the idea I can't protect them when their embedded on a page unfortunately.

Comment: Typekit's protection seems to be good enough for most font foundries. Of curse you can crack it and download it. But you can do the same with SWF files.

Comment: With embedded font, you can happily find the URL of the ttf font and grab it. This is acceptable for CC fonts, but for fonts on a propriety license we would be breaking the licensing law to do that. With Flash - understandably it could be hacked - but you can limit, or even vectorize the font set - thus at worst only allowing the downloader a limit character set.

Comment: well typekit, webfonts.fonts.com and others have managed to negotiate agreements to allow @font-face. While it is still possible to illegally obtain a font through those services it is harden then just downloading and then installing the font.

Answer (score 2):

1. Where you can't make certain aspects of a website stay the same across platforms.
2. Where you cannot do what you want with anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Flash can...

- access the web cam
- access the microphone
- access sockets in all browsers

flash has...

- a gui for creating complex vector animations
- an elegant system for managing and nesting visual assets
- built in filters like blur and convolution that run in real-time
- real-time bitmap manipulation with BitmapData and PixelBender (much faster than canvas)
- software rendered 3d engines like PV3D or Away3D
- real-time audio manipulation for generating audio and processing existing audio files
- the ability to read and write binary data, enabling the reading and writing of any filetype (like pdf or doc)

There's more but those are the main ones I can think of off the top of my head. I've been using lots of HTML5 lately and I think it's really excellent, but when it comes time to make games or do something related to the above list, I still find myself using flash.

Recently while developing games in flash I've been thinking to myself how I would go about doing the same thing using canvas and/or javascript and HTML5. In some cases it's possible, but in most cases it would be a good deal more work and code.

Answer (score 1):

these spring to mind:

- Augmented reality applications
- P2P and other video applications; videochat
- Rich media banners (there are good solutions to this in HTML5 though) and mostly interactive online advertising
- Applications for Flash-Lite and Flash Player 10 enabled mobile devices (Set top boxes, XBox etc)

Rob

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a website for an upscale restaurant, you **must** use flash.

Bonus points if it has a sweet looking loading screen that plays ambient music.

here is an example of a good flash UI:

http://www.rinconlimenorestaurant.com

Comment: if that's your ever website you really 'must' :D

Comment: hope this is a sarcastic answer, that is the only reason this doesn't get a big old downvote from me, I am assuming you are trying to be funny

Comment: That's your go-to site for decent Flash? I'm going to leave the down vote as you have a good rep - and you must be stating this for humour.

Comment: yes its a joke! sheesh, one thing i noticed at SO is that on avg no one has any sense of humor. that site btw is the worst flash website ive ever seen

Comment: Really!? Thats the worst flash site you've ever seen? I won't down you as I think you're joking... :P ->This is the worst flash site *ever* http://superior-web-solutions.com/

Comment: Glycerine: i see your point, but the site i linked to is of a restaurant i used to visit. try finding their menu, its like the site is made to make that task impossibly hard.

Comment: Maybe we should have a vote humour up and down button...

Comment: well if anything i thing funny answers shouldn't be voted down, but also shouldn't be voted up.